# Scrapy spider only extracts first table element

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this URL: 'search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot'. For the begining I am just interested in the titel and the category which is illustrated in the screenshot below. However when I run my spider I get back only the first element:

```
{'titel': 'MindSphere – open ', 
'category': ' operating system - Software - Siemens Global Website'}
```

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy

class SiemensHtmlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens_html'
    allowed_domains = ['search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot']
    start_urls = ['http://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #//dl[@id='search-resultlist']/dt/a
        for element in response.xpath("//dl[@id='search-resultlist']"):
            yield {
                'titel': element.xpath('//dt/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
                'category': element.xpath('//dt/a/text()[2]').extract_first()
            }
```

And here my screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
yield {
    'titel': element.xpath('//dt/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
    'category': element.xpath('//dt/a/text()[2]').extract_first()
}
```

With:

```
yield {
    'titel': element.xpath('.//dt/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
    'category': element.xpath('.//dt/a/text()[2]').extract_first()
}
```

Pay attention to dots in front of xpath selector, they mean relative path.

UPD: just small tip, also check your `allowed_domains` value. It should be written in this way: `allowed_domains = ['search.siemens.com']`

UPD2: also problem in main selector in `for` loop, better be more presice and point on concrete blocks list.

```
for element in response.xpath("//dl[@id='search-resultlist']/dt"):
    yield {
        'titel': element.xpath('.//a/text()[1]').get(),
        'category': element.xpath('.//a/text()[2]').get()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Vezunchik, thank you for answering. I did as you asked however the problem remains

Comment: Got it. Updated answer.

Comment: The for loop was the problem. Thank you now it works!